# Как установить связь между несколькими combobox в python используя данные из БД sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite3, combobox

Недавно начал изучать python столкнулся с таким вопрос, как связать несколько combobox. 
Смысл в вот в чем:
Имеется база данных SQlite 3. В ней таблица со столбцами:
id, marka, model 
Так как в базе уже вручную введено более 1500 наименований автотранспорта.
Хотелось сделать следующие: что при выборе в 1 комбобоксе допустим марки ВАЗ во 2 комбобоксе была возможность выбора моделей всех моделей авто данной марки которые в БД.
Первый комбобокс я заполняю, но не могу понять произвести взаимосвязь со вторым.
Часть кода по заполнению 1 комбобокса

```
# первый комбобокс
    self.combobox_marka = ttk.Combobox(self)
    self.combobox_marka['values'] = self.marka()
    self.combobox_marka.pack()
    self.combobox_marka.current(0)
    self.combobox_marka.place(x=250, y=60)
# второй комбобокс  
    self.combobox_number_avto = ttk.Combobox(self)
    self.combobox_number_avto['values'] = self.number()
    self.combobox_number_avto.pack()

    self.combobox_number_avto.current(0)
    self.combobox_number_avto.place(x=250, y=60)
    # взаимосвязь 1 комбобокса с таблицей из БД
    def marka(self):
         cursor = self.db.cursor()
         cursor.execute('SELECT marka FROM avto_sl')
         data = []
         for row in cursor.fetchall():
             data.append(row[0])
         return data
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимальный пример демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Всес изменение в начальный предосталвенный код